# Is there a list of exception error class values and what they mean? Specifically sqlexception

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, exception

I'm working some with a database and catching exceptions to check for various conditions. I can't simply catch the sqlException, since it can mean a lot of things, and usually use

```
catch (SqlException e)
        {
            if (e.Errors[0].Class == 14)
            {
                return 0;
            }
            else ........
```

To check for specific cases. In this example, class 14 (at least as far as I can tell) signifies a duplicate entry. A different class means the server can't be found, or refusing the connection, or login error, etc. Does anyone know where a list of these error classes could be found? Googling this is difficult since anything with "class" in it turns up the obvious.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `Class` property of the `SqlError` class actually indicates the severity of the error. For the type of error, look in the [`Number`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlerror.number.aspx) property. You can also use the [`Message`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlerror.message.aspx) property to get a string describing the error. You can find the list of server error messages [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645603.aspx).

Comment: I wanted to avoid checking the message string itself. I was once told that's very bad form, since you have to check an equality of an entire string. Looks like Number might be what I need, I need to read through that msdn page, thanks!

Comment: Yes, use `Number` for that decision. You can use the `Message` when it's an error you weren't expecting (log it internally, but don't present the message to the user).

Comment: Yep, right now, all unexpected exceptions are written to a debug log

Answer (score 6):

A severity of 14 can mean a lot of things:

```
SELECT message_id, [text]
FROM sys.messages
WHERE language_id = 1033
AND severity = 14;
```

To see the full list:

```
SELECT message_id, severity, [text]
FROM sys.messages
WHERE language_id = 1033
AND severity > 0
ORDER BY severity;
```

I suspect you are more interested in the message_id column than the severity column, as that is a little more specific.