# Sql Server Transient Exception Numbers

Tags: c#, sql-server

I want to write some wrapper code to my database calls (using C#, and a Microsoft technology for accessing the database), auto-retrying on a 'transient' exception. By transient, I mean something that there is a good chance will resolve eventually (as against logically errors that will never work). Examples that I can think of include:

- Deadlock
- Connection Timeout
- Command timeout

I had planned on using SqlException's error numbers to spot these. So for example:

```
List<RunStoredProcedureResultType> resultSet = null;
int limit = 3;
for (int i = 0; i < limit; ++i)
{
    bool isLast = i == limit - 1;
    try
    {
        using (var db = /* ... */)
        {
            resultSet = db.RunStoredProcedure(param1, param2).ToList();
        }
        //if it gets here it was successful
        break;
    }
    catch (SqlException ex)
    {
        if (isLast)
        {
            //3 transient errors in a row. So just kill it
            throw;
        }
        switch (ex.Number)
        {
            case 1205: //deadlock
            case -2:   //timeout (command timeout?)
            case 11:   //timeout (connection timeout?)
                // do nothing - continue the loop
                break;
            default:
                //a non-transient error. Just throw the exception on
                throw;
        }
    }
    Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1)); //some kind of delay - might not use Sleep
}
return resultSet;
```

(excuse me for any bugs - I've just written that on the fly. I also realise I could wrap it up nicely...)

So the key question is: what numbers should I consider 'transient' (I realise what I consider transient may be different to what other people consider transient). I've found a nice list here:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645603.aspx

but its massive and note very useful. **Has anyone else built up a list that they use for something similar?**

**UPDATE**

In the end, we opted for a 'bad list' - if the error is a one of a list of known 'non-transient errors' - which are generally programmer errors. I've included a list of numbers we are using as an answer.

Comment: we did something similar. called it "recoverable exceptions". including connectivity errors, timeouts and deadlocks. but: deadlocks are likely to persevere when you just repeat the call thrice - consider adding a variable delay or other deadlock resolution methods. and a connection timeout due to overload might also get worse when you fire two retries immediately.

Comment: Oh yes, I had planned a delay. Thanks @dlatikay - will update the above

Comment: Hi, you are asking for a recommendation, unfortunately it is not a solvable question because any programmer may have a different opinion of what would be useful for your case, so with the way it is currently redacted it's off topic; regards.

Comment: An idea would have been to classify by severity, see here: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa937483(v=sql.80).aspx but unfortunately, the exception class for resource-related errors combines things like "out of disk space" and "locks" in one level. also confirmed here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9405648/is-there-a-list-of-exception-error-class-values-and-what-they-mean-specifically

Comment: @jclozano would not fully agree. the list of recoverable errors should in fact be deterministc. Microsoft went only half the way though. They have classified errors in levels like "warning", "error that can be corrected by the user", and "error related to resources" etc., but not in a way like "recoverable by repetition/timing/modified call context" versus "permanent error"

Comment: Deadlocks are unlikely to persevere because killing one party allows the other one to make progress. On the next try the killed party will wait on some new lock that has appeared but it will no longer deadlock. Blocking != deadlocking.

Comment: @dlatikay what i mean is that some transient errors may not apply to the OP development, system and or architecture therefore making the list that is useful to him a subset of a truly complete list (as we can see by his commment of the microsoft list being massive), so we would have to judge what is useful for him.

Comment: I would argue it doesn't matter if it's transient or not. Just try x-times and then give up. It should be an rare-exceptional case that production code tries accessing a missing table.

Comment: @RobertPaulsen - I'd be tempted to edge on that side of caution, but sometimes it is just not worth retrying - such as `String or binary data would be truncated`, or `Cannot insert the value NULL` will never succeed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sorry to answer my own question, but if anyone is still interested, we've just started building up our own list of error codes. Not ideal, but we figured this shouldn't happen too often.

We opted for a 'bad list' approach, instead of the 'good list' as implied in the question. The ids we have so far are:

```
PARAMETER_NOT_SUPPLIED = 201;
CANNOT_INSERT_NULL_INTO_NON_NULL = 515;
FOREGIN_KEY_VIOLATION = 547;
PRIMARY_KEY_VIOLATION = 2627;
MEMORY_ALLOCATION_FAILED = 4846;
ERROR_CONVERTING_NUMERIC_TO_DECIMAL = 8114; 
TOO_MANY_ARGUMENTS = 8144;
ARGUMENT_IS_NOT_A_PARAMETER = 8145;
ARGS_SUPPLIED_FOR_PROCEDURE_WITHOUT_PARAMETERS = 8146;
STRING_OR_BINARY_TRUNCATED = 8152;
INVALID_POINTER = 10006;
WRONG_NUMBER_OF_PARAMETERS = 18751;
```

Another thing we noticed is that if the connection pool times out you don't get a SqlException - instead you get a InvalidOperationException reporting "Timeout expired". It's a shame its not a SqlException but well worth catching.

I'll try to keep this up to date with any additions.

Answer (score 11):

There's a class `[SqlDatabaseTransientErrorDetectionStrategy.cs]` in sql Azure for transient fault handling. It covers almost all types of exception code that can be considered as transient. Also it's a complete implementation of a `Retry strategy`.

Adding the snippet here for future reference:

```
/// <summary>
/// Error codes reported by the DBNETLIB module.
/// </summary>
private enum ProcessNetLibErrorCode
{
    ZeroBytes = -3,

    Timeout = -2,
    /* Timeout expired. The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding. */

    Unknown = -1,

    InsufficientMemory = 1,

    AccessDenied = 2,

    ConnectionBusy = 3,

    ConnectionBroken = 4,

    ConnectionLimit = 5,

    ServerNotFound = 6,

    NetworkNotFound = 7,

    InsufficientResources = 8,

    NetworkBusy = 9,

    NetworkAccessDenied = 10,

    GeneralError = 11,

    IncorrectMode = 12,

    NameNotFound = 13,

    InvalidConnection = 14,

    ReadWriteError = 15,

    TooManyHandles = 16,

    ServerError = 17,

    SSLError = 18,

    EncryptionError = 19,

    EncryptionNotSupported = 20
}
```

Further a switch case to check if the error number returned in sql exception:

```
switch (err.Number)
{
    // SQL Error Code: 40501
    // The service is currently busy. Retry the request after 10 seconds. Code: (reason code to be decoded).
    case ThrottlingCondition.ThrottlingErrorNumber:
        // Decode the reason code from the error message to determine the grounds for throttling.
        var condition = ThrottlingCondition.FromError(err);

        // Attach the decoded values as additional attributes to the original SQL exception.
        sqlException.Data[condition.ThrottlingMode.GetType().Name] =
            condition.ThrottlingMode.ToString();
        sqlException.Data[condition.GetType().Name] = condition;

        return true;

    // SQL Error Code: 10928
    // Resource ID: %d. The %s limit for the database is %d and has been reached.
    case 10928:
    // SQL Error Code: 10929
    // Resource ID: %d. The %s minimum guarantee is %d, maximum limit is %d and the current usage for the database is %d. 
    // However, the server is currently too busy to support requests greater than %d for this database.
    case 10929:
    // SQL Error Code: 10053
    // A transport-level error has occurred when receiving results from the server.
    // An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine.
    case 10053:
    // SQL Error Code: 10054
    // A transport-level error has occurred when sending the request to the server. 
    // (provider: TCP Provider, error: 0 - An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.)
    case 10054:
    // SQL Error Code: 10060
    // A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. 
    // The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server 
    // is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 0 - A connection attempt failed 
    // because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed 
    // because connected host has failed to respond.)"}
    case 10060:
    // SQL Error Code: 40197
    // The service has encountered an error processing your request. Please try again.
    case 40197:
    // SQL Error Code: 40540
    // The service has encountered an error processing your request. Please try again.
    case 40540:
    // SQL Error Code: 40613
    // Database XXXX on server YYYY is not currently available. Please retry the connection later. If the problem persists, contact customer 
    // support, and provide them the session tracing ID of ZZZZZ.
    case 40613:
    // SQL Error Code: 40143
    // The service has encountered an error processing your request. Please try again.
    case 40143:
    // SQL Error Code: 233
    // The client was unable to establish a connection because of an error during connection initialization process before login. 
    // Possible causes include the following: the client tried to connect to an unsupported version of SQL Server; the server was too busy 
    // to accept new connections; or there was a resource limitation (insufficient memory or maximum allowed connections) on the server. 
    // (provider: TCP Provider, error: 0 - An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.)
    case 233:
    // SQL Error Code: 64
    // A connection was successfully established with the server, but then an error occurred during the login process. 
    // (provider: TCP Provider, error: 0 - The specified network name is no longer available.) 
    case 64:
    // DBNETLIB Error Code: 20
    // The instance of SQL Server you attempted to connect to does not support encryption.
    case (int)ProcessNetLibErrorCode.EncryptionNotSupported:
        return true;
}
```

See complete [source here](https://github.com/Azure/elastic-db-tools/blob/master/Src/ElasticScale.Client/ElasticScale.Common/TransientFaultHandling/Implementation/SqlDatabaseTransientErrorDetectionStrategy.cs).

Comment: This is good. Just adding a note that this list still is not complete. The EF is just as clueless about this as anyone else. They forget items. Example: Snapshot isolation write conflicts. Also I don't see deadlock on that list which means the list of of very questionable value.

Comment: Thanks @vendettamit - looks good but as usr mentions, the fact it misses a deadlock makes me feel a tad suspicious as that is probably one of the main ones I'd be interested in retrying on. I guess maybe it's not something that EF can just decide to retry automatically for though?

Comment: @vendettamit - Can you update your answer with your mention of the missing errors that usr has in his comments? It'll be good enough to be the answer I reckon then

Comment: You run the query that @usr provided on sql server and get the desired codes you're interested in. E.g. deadlock codes that you want to include can be filtered as `SELECT * FROM sys.messages WHERE language_id = 1033 And text LIKE '%deadlock%'`

Answer (score 4):

There is no canonical list of retryable codes. Other teams have had this problem before. The EF team has developed a retry strategy. You might want to raid their code. But the list is not complete. I have seen EF commits on GitHub where they amended the list.

I had this problem as well. I added some obvious error codes that I dug out from `SELECT * FROM sys.messages WHERE language_id = 1033 AND text LIKE '%...%'`. Then, I added codes as the app encountered them.

You also need to retry on the special error number for timeout and for network error. The server cannot generate that number because the connection is dropped. I think the number was -2 but you need to make sure.

The error levels that SQL Server defines are useless for this purpose (and mostly in general).

Answer (score 1):

We're using vendettamit's list and keep extending it whenever we stumble across another error code that we determine to be transient. It's important to note that out definition of transient is "it's worth a retry, maybe it'll work the next time" and not necessary SQL Server problem. So far, we've added the following codes:

- 53: An error has occurred while establishing a connection to the server.
- 109: Pipe was ended (only needed if you connect via Named Pipes to local SQL Servers)
- 11004: could not connect (usually means client network is not ready yet)
- 17142: server is paused (handy for testing behaviour when the SQL server "disappears" for a bit)

When you know that your conenction string is good (i.e. because you've managed to establish a connection very recently), you can add the following codes. Again, you should *not* use these for retrying to establishing the initial connection, these can also pop up if you have bad parameters in your connection string.

- 11001: host not found (can appear on a network change)
- 1326: bad username or password (we've seen this pop up when pulling the virtual ethernet cable on VMs)
- 258: server was not found (no TCP answer)